# Read inputs from a file linux/bash

Tags: linux, bash

I tried to write a program that can sum up all the inputs read from another file called test

my program sum:

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
for n; do
 sum=$(($sum + $n)
done
echo $sum
```

and my test file test.in:

```
1
2
3
```

However, After entering

```
./sum < test.in
```

Nothing was displayed.

How should fix my code?

Thanks

Comment: You have got two answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337424/redirect-input-from-a-file-to-a-program). Have you read them? Do not duplicate questions it is a bad practice.

Comment: you can confirm you script is actually running by adding a "label" to your output, i.e. `echo "sum=$sum"`. BUT where do you have the code that is reading input from your file? Look here for examples `while read line [linux]`. Good luck.

Comment: Voting to close because this is a duplicate of  your Q on http:unix.stackexchange.com . Thanks to @sorontar for pointing that out! Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to read every line from `test.in`, rewrite your script to *read* each line:

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
while read n; do
  sum=$(($sum + $n))
done
echo $sum
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to doing in a way other then pure `bash`, you can try in `awk`:

```
awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'  < test.in
```